# NSPredicate not parsing and crashing

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad, nspredicate

i am trying to make a common method to get NSPredicates, which are throwing parsing errors.However if i code inline some thing like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicateTax_added = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tax_added = %@",@"YES"];
```

it works.

however below doesn't work:

```
NSPredicate *predicateTax_added = [self createPredicateWithFormateWhereKey:@"tax_added" operator:NSEqualToPredicateOperatorType value:@"YES"];

-(NSPredicate *)createPredicateWithFormateWhereKey:(NSString *)key operator:(NSPredicateOperatorType *)operatorType value:(NSString *)value
{
return [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@",key, operatorType, value];
}
```

any suggestion , thanks.

Comment: Why not you pass directly @"="..

Comment: @SunnyShah: `%@` in predicateWithFormat is only for *values*, substituting `@"="` as an *operator* would not work. You could use stringWithFormat first, but that is error-prone in the case of any special quoting characters.

Comment: @MartinR yes you are right predicateWithFormat will not take directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in the line

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@",key, operatorType, value]
```

- To substitute a *key* you have to use the `%K` format instead of `%@`.
- There is no way so substitute an *operator* in `predicateWithFormat`.

To build a predicate from a variable key, value and operator, you have to construct
the predicate programmatically:

```
-(NSPredicate *)createPredicateWithFormateWhereKey:(NSString *)key operator:(NSPredicateOperatorType)operatorType value:(NSString *)value
{
    NSExpression *left = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:key];
    NSExpression *right = [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:value];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSComparisonPredicate
                              predicateWithLeftExpression:left
                              rightExpression:right
                              modifier:0
                              type:operatorType
                              options:0];
    return predicate;
}
```

Note also that `NSPredicateOperatorType` is a *scalar* and not an object, and must
therefore not be passed as a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar predicate-method, `predicateWithSubstitutionVariables`

See more here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html

I don't think `predicateWithFormat` can be used like you do.